# Pandas File Not Found Error -- Worked Yesterday

Tags: python, pandas

Yesterday I imported an sas file into Pandas, and was able to successfully poke around the data. This morning, I received a file not found error, although I did not move any files.

I triple-checked the path and it was correct. Then I tried placing a copy of the file on my desktop and redirecting read command. Same error. (This is the type of thing that makes you feel crazy.) Any help appreciated.

[image: screen capture of file not found error in Pandas]

Comment: can you try with complete path instead of relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless that you have a folder named `Dropbox` inside your project directory, I suggest you use the full path of your file:

`/home/<username>/Dropbox/Thesis Fall 2017/Data Analysis/epcg17.xpt`

**OR**

`~/Dropbox/Thesis Fall 2017/Data Analysis/epcg17.xpt`

Both should work.

Comment: Just a tip: If you use `~/Dropbox/Thesis Fall 2017/Data Analysis/epcg17.xpt` you might want to wrap it in the `os.path.expanduser()` function to get the full path.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Any thoughts why the relative path worked yesterday and not this morning?

Comment: @DoughnutDayDevotee - It depends on how your `sys.path` was setup or the the current working directory to which Jupyter was set.