# I am trying to upload this tsv file but I receive this error, even though the directory is correct

Tags: python, pandas, filenotfounderror

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('../TextFiles/moviereviews.tsv', sep='\t')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bc1b802aa39e> in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 
----> 4 df = pd.read_csv('../TextFiles/moviereviews.tsv', sep='\t')
      5 df.head()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    609 
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    611 
    612 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    460 
    461     # Create the parser.
--> 462     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    463 
    464     if chunksize or iterator:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    817             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    818 
--> 819         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    820 
    821     def close(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1048             )
   1049         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1050         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1051 
   1052     def _failover_to_python(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1865 
   1866         # open handles
-> 1867         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
   1868         assert self.handles is not None
   1869         for key in ("storage_options", "encoding", "memory_map", "compression"):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
   1360         Let the readers open IOHanldes after they are done with their potential raises.
   1361         """
-> 1362         self.handles = get_handle(
   1363             src,
   1364             "r",

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    640                 errors = "replace"
    641             # Encoding
--> 642             handle = open(
    643                 handle,
    644                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../TextFiles/moviereviews.tsv'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas File Not Found Error -- Worked Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169413/pandas-file-not-found-error-worked-yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug with `pathlib`:

```
import pathlib

relative_path = pathlib.Path('../TextFiles/moviereviews.tsv')

absolute_path = relative_path.resolve()

print(f"Is '{absolute_path}' file exist: {'yes' if absolute_path.exists() else 'no'}")
```

Output:

```
Is '/home/corralien/devel/TextFiles/moviereviews.tsv' file exist: no
```